# Apply CSS and Javascript affect to images

Tags: javascript, theming, media

**Updated**

I am trying to add CSS and Javascript hover affect to some images in drupal 7 .. something like in this tutorial.

http://callmenick.com/2014/03/06/image-overlay-hover-effects-with-css3-t ...
Hover on some touch devices is sticky like iphone .. in this example it gives the user a (X) which close the sticky hover when it is touched

i have jQuery Update already installed ... and when i applied the code like in this tutorial in custom CSS and Javascript files .. its not working ... i really do not know what am i doing wrong or if i have to install another library to drupal or what am i missing to add to drupal ... even when i try to test it here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/onsyH ... still not working ..

any help will be appreciated

Comment: This question is off topic as it has nothing to do with Drupal.

Comment: is that your help????? and how it has nothing to do with drupal ?????

Comment: You are following a demo to create CSS overlay hover effects. Tell me how it DOES have anything to do with Drupal?

Comment: any php, mysql, html, css or javascript have something to do with drupal ... there difference if you didn't understand my question ... and then you should ask for explanation not just write it has nothing to do with drupal !!!!!!!

Comment: Thanks for your effort ... but that is something that i can do ... and my question is not about that ... the hover affect doesn't work on some touch devices except with javascript .... therefore i am asking this question ..

another reason is that i am using drupal and i am asking is there is anything wrong that i am doing or forgetting to apply any library or something like that.
I hope it is more clear now for you

Comment: Fair enough, please see updated answer. The JS may not be working because in your code pen, you are using $ instead of jQuery, so you need to wrap it in a jQuery function.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about implementing a functionality, or a layout seen in a site, for which only a screenshot or a site URL is provided. See [Help Center](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: If you're having trouble with code you've written, please be sure to include the relevant portions to reproduce the problem in the question itself, not on an external site. Please be aware that just because you are using Drupal to create a particular CSS/JS layout, doesn't make it on topic here. For that, the question needs to he _about_ Drupal, not just about CSS/JS you want use with Drupal. Please see the [help] for more details of the types of question we answer here. Thanks

Comment: Yes you are all right ... that was my mistake because i couldn't explain what i need clearly ... i updated my question and i hope i made it more clear now ... sorry for my poor English and Thanks to you all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done a CSS only alternative for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/bk5h7/

**EDIT:** In answer to the JS not working in Drupal, you may need to wrap any document ready JS in behaviour tabs, and/or declare jQuery.

This will also help if you use it in a view that uses AJAX. Putting it in a behaviour instead of document ready, means the JS will load again even on every AJAX request.

```
(function($) {
Drupal.behaviors.myBehavior = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {

        // Put your jQuery Code Here

  }
};
})(jQuery);
```

**EDIT 2:** The demo uses jQuery 1.9.1, whereas Drupal 7 is shipped with 1.4.4. Maybe try using the [jQuery Update](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module to update your version.

**EDIT 3:** What are you using to load the Modernizr.js script? That touch function you are talking about relies on device detection using Modernizr.js.

Copy the modernizr.js file to your themes JS folder, and in your themes template.php file, try adding...

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'YOUR_THEME') . '/js/modernizr.js');
```

Comment: Again ... thanks a lot for you effort and your better ANSWER .. but it is still not what i need ... still not working on iphone ... in the tutorial it gives the img a closing button which appear just on touch phone .. so when hover affect happen on touch phone you get an X button to close it ... again thanks for your help and i will survive your minus rating :)

Comment: That function is using the if(Modernizr.touch). Are you definitely calling modenizr.js? How are you adding the JS? Can you edit your question, and i will be able to remove bad rating.

Comment: Please see updated answer.

Comment: again thank you very much for your help ... i will update my post and try what you are telling me ... and i didn't see that i have to load Modernizr.js script .. and i have jQuery Update module already installed .. i am really trying to do it for at least now 1 month and i couldn't find any solution ... thanks a lot

Comment: Yeah, at the top of the demo page you posted, click the "get source" and download the complete folder of code. If a demo provides Source, often the code in the demo is only the major parts explained.

Comment: Thank you very much ... finally i got it to work ... the main problem was that i didn't attach modenizr.js file ... it did work good when i applied it to theme.info .. again thank you very much for your help

Comment: No worries, glad you sorted it! I changed my vote on your question btw :)